# How to activate a Script only if a specific Window is active?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a problem with a Script which should just do the following:
- If a specific Window becomes active
- SetCapslockState, On
- If the Windows lost focus
- SetCapslockState, Off

I've tried:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class blahblah")

SetCapslockState, On
```

and/or

```
#If !WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1")

SetCapslockState, Off
```

But it don't work.

Also I've tried:

```
WinWaitActive, (mytitleofwindow)
if ErrorLevel
{
SetCapslockState, On

return
}
else
```

It don't work either, else I would not ask for help here... hihihi

I hope someone can help me! :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a loop (which takes up CPU cycles), you can also use Hardware Handles. See example:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
Menu, Tray, Tip, Medical Alert
SetKeyDelay, 50
Menu, Tray, Icon , Shell32.dll, 145, 1
TrayTip, Medical Alert, Started, 1

Gui +LastFound 
hWnd := WinExist()
DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,Hwnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam ) ; Run on Window switch
{
    If (wParam = 4) ; If Window Changed
    {        
        WinGetActiveTitle, Title
        if instr(Title, "Past Medical History") OR instr(Title, "Allergies Verified") ; TESTED WITH: if instr(Title, "NotePad")
            MsgBox, 1, Allergies Verified, Please verify patient allergies
    }
}
Return
```

Comment: IMO, your solution is the preferred method. `SetWinEventHook` could be used as an alternative to `RegisterShellHookWindow` if looking for finer control.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to combine [WinWait[Not]Active](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) with a [Loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm).

```
Loop {
    WinWaitActive, mytitleofwindow
    SetCapslockState, On
    WinWaitNotActive, mytitleofwindow
    SetCapslockState, Off
}
```